# Pycuda: Best way of calling Kernel multiple times

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I'm using pycuda to make a relativistic raytracer. Basically, for each "pixel" in a big 2D array we must solve a system of 6 ODEs using Runge Kutta. As each integration is independent of the rest it should be very easy. Other people has achieve it using C/C++ CUDA with excellent results (see [this project](https://github.com/chanchikwan/gray)).

The problem arises in the fact that I do not know how is the best way of doing this. I'm writing a Kernel that does some Runge Kutta Steps and then return the results to the CPU. This Kernel is called a lot of times in order to get the whole ray integrated. The problem is for some reason **is very slow**. Of course, I know that memory transfers are really a Bottleneck in CUDA, but as this is really slow I'm starting to think that I'm doing something wrong.

It would be great if you can recommend me best programming practices for this case. (Using pycuda). Some things that I'm wandering:

1. Do I need to create a new context on reach Kernel call?
2. There is a way to *not have to* transfer memory from GPU to CPU, that is, starting a Kernel, pausing it to get *some* information, restating it and repeat.
3. Each RK4 iteration takes roughly half a second, which is insane (also compared with the CUDA code in the link that does some similar operation). And I think this is due to something wrong with the way I'm using pycuda, so if you can explain the best way to do such an operation in the best manner, it could be great!.

To clarify: the reason I have to pause/restart the Kernel is because of the watchdog. Kernels of more than 10 seconds got killed by the watchdog.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main question seems to be too general, and it's hard to give some concrete advice without seeing the code. I'll try to answer your subquestions (not an actual answer, but it's a bit long for a comment)

> Do I need to create a new context on reach Kernel call?

No.

> There is a way to not have to transfer memory from GPU to CPU, that is, starting a Kernel, pausing it to get some information, restating it and repeat.

Depends on what you mean by "get some information". If it means doing stuff with it on CPU, then, of course, you have to transfer it. If you want to use in another kernel invocation, then you don't need to transfer it.

> Each RK4 iteration takes roughly half a second, which is insane (also compared with the CUDA code in the link that does some similar operation).

It really depends on the equation, the number of threads and the video card you are using. I can imagine a situation when one RK step would take that long.

> And I think this is due to something wrong with the way I'm using pycuda, so if you can explain the best way to do such an operation in the best manner, it could be great!.

Impossible to say for sure without the code. Try to create some minimal demonstrating example, or, at the very least, post a link to a **runnable** (even if it's rather long) piece of code that illustrates your problem. As for PyCUDA, it's a very thin wrapper over CUDA, and all the programming practises that apply to the latter, apply to the former as well.

Answer (score -1):

I might help you with the memory handling, i.e. not having to copy from CPU to GPU during your iterations. I am evolving a system through time using euler timestepping, and the way I keep all my data on my GPU is given below. 
However, the problem with this is that once the first kernel has been launched, the cpu keeps executing the lines after it. I.e. the boundary kernel gets launched before the time evolution step.

What I need is a way to synchronize things. I have tried doing it using strm.synchronize() (see my code) but it does not always work. If you have any ideas on this, I would really appreciate your input! Thanks!

```
def curveShorten(dist,timestep,maxit):
"""
iterates the function image on a 2d grid through an euler anisotropic
diffusion operator with timestep=timestep maxit number of times
"""
image = 1*dist
forme = image.shape
if(np.size(forme)>2):
    sys.exit('Only works on gray images')

aSize = forme[0]*forme[1]
xdim  = np.int32(forme[0])
ydim  = np.int32(forme[1])  


image[0,:]      = image[1,:]
image[xdim-1,:] = image[xdim-2,:]
image[:,ydim-1] = image[:,ydim-2]
image[:,0]      = image[:,1]

#np arrays  i need to store things on the CPU, image is the initial 
#condition and final is the final state
image = image.reshape(aSize,order= 'C').astype(np.float32)
final = np.zeros(aSize).astype(np.float32)

#allocating memory to GPUs
image_gpu = drv.mem_alloc(image.nbytes)
final_gpu = drv.mem_alloc(final.nbytes)

#sending data to each memory location
drv.memcpy_htod(image_gpu,image) #host to device copying
drv.memcpy_htod(final_gpu,final)

#block size: B := dim1*dim2*dim3=1024
#gird size : dim1*dimr2*dim3 = ceiling(aSize/B)
blockX     = int(1024)
multiplier = aSize/float(1024)   
if(aSize/float(1024) > int(aSize/float(1024)) ):
    gridX = int(multiplier + 1)
else:
    gridX = int(multiplier)
strm1 = drv.Stream(1)
ev1   = drv.Event()
strm2 = drv.Stream()
for k in range(0,maxit):

    Kern_diffIteration(image_gpu,final_gpu,ydim, xdim, np.float32(timestep), block=(blockX,1,1), grid=(gridX,1,1),stream=strm1)
    strm1.synchronize()

    if(strm1.is_done()==1):
     Kern_boundaryX0(final_gpu,ydim,xdim,block=(blockX,1,1), grid=(gridX,1,1))
     Kern_boundaryX1(final_gpu,ydim,xdim,block=(blockX,1,1), grid=(gridX,1,1))#,stream=strm1)
     Kern_boundaryY0(final_gpu,ydim,xdim,block=(blockX,1,1), grid=(gridX,1,1))#,stream=strm2)
     Kern_boundaryY1(final_gpu,ydim,xdim,block=(blockX,1,1), grid=(gridX,1,1))#,stream=strm1)

    if(strm1.is_done()==1): 
      drv.memcpy_dtod(image_gpu, final_gpu, final.nbytes)
    #Kern_copy(image_gpu,final_gpu,ydim,xdim,block=(blockX,1,1), grid=(gridX,1,1),stream=strm1)



drv.memcpy_dtoh(final,final_gpu) #device to host copying
#final_gpu.free()
#image_gpu.free()


return final.reshape(forme,order='C')
```

Comment: This is not an anwer to the original question. Pleas consider posting this as a *new* question